# jQuery Custom Plugin for submit button disabled/enabled

Tags: jquery

I've multiple forms on my website and i want to change the ***disabled attribute of submit button*** whenever all the inputs have some value in it.

Instead of copy pasting same line of code for each form element i decided to create a basic plugin so that i can call it on any form i want but, the problem is ***whenever i call the function it gives an error in console***

> Uncaught ReferenceError: buttonToggle is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement. (custom.js:35)

***Here's my jQuery plugin code***

```
$.fn.buttonToggle = function() {
    var empty = false;
    $(this).each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
    if (empty) {
        $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
};

//calling function on forms 

$('#user-login-form input').on('keyup change', function(){
    buttonToggle();
});

$('#user-signup input').on('keyup change', function(){
    buttonToggle();
});
```

Please guide me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: check if you have jquery lib on the page at the top

Comment: you are not passing value to the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added `buttonToggle()` as a plugin/extension to jquery:

```
$.fn.buttonToggle = function() ...
```

you can now call this as a jquery function:

```
$(this).buttonToggle()
```

inside your keyup/change event handler, giving:

```
$.fn.buttonToggle = function() {
    var empty = false;
    $(this).each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
    if (empty) {
        $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
};

//calling function on forms 

$('form input').on('keyup change', function(){
    $(this).buttonToggle();
});
```

This will get your .buttonToggle function to be called, but there are other errors - specifically, you use `$(this).each` inside, which implies more than one input, so should probably be

```
$('form input').on('keyup change', function(){
    $(this).closest("form").buttonToggle();
});
```

and

```
$.fn.buttonToggle = function() {
    var empty = false;
    $(this).find("input").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
```

you should also add chaining by returning `this` at the end of your function.

Comment: Thanks for answering. i have multiple forms on single page it enables all forms buttons only if one input have value & ignoring all other forms inputs. how can i trigger a button of a specific form whose input has value ?

Comment: This question was about why `buttonToggle()` wasn't working; which has been answered.  Please ask a new question regarding making your plugin work for multiple forms on the same page and the submit buttons within them.  You should get an answer relatively quickly with a new question (post link here if you like).

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the jQuery function, you are calling a global function called buttonToggle. To make it work do this:

```
$('#user-login-form input').on('keyup change', function(){
    $('#user-login-form').buttonToggle();
});

$('#user-signup input').on('keyup change', function(){
    $('#user-signup').buttonToggle();
});
```

Possibly a plugin is an overkill. You can change the event handler to this:

```js
function toggleButton() {
  var empty = $(this).parent().find("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value === "";
  });
  if (empty.length > 0) {
    $('input[type="button"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('input[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}

$('#user-login-form input, #user-signup input').on('keyup change', toggleButton);
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user-login-form">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div id="user-signup">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<input type='button' value='This is a button' disabled>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.The problem with above code is that it only enables button when first input element has some value and disables if value is less than 0. i want all inputs (i.e email & password) to have some value and then only the button will be enabled.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to. I added a snippet to my answer. It is working fine.